# Why Django 1.4 per-site cache does not work correctly with CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY?

Tags: django

I am working on a Django 1.4 project and writing one simple application using per-site cache as described here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache

I have correctly setup a local Memcached server and confirmed the pages are being cached.

Then I set CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY = True because I don't want to cache pages for authenticated users.

I'm testing with a simple view that returns a template with render_to_response and RequestContext to be able to access user information from the template and the caching works well so far, meaning it caches pages just for anonymous users.

And here's my problem. I created another view using a different template that doesn't access user information and noticed that the page was being cached even if the user was authenticated. After testing many things I found that authenticated users were getting a cached page if the template didn't print something from the user context variable. It's very simple to test: print the user on the template and the page won't be cached for an authenticated user, remove the user on the template, refresh the page while authenticated and check the HTTP headers and you will notice you're getting a cached page. You should clear the cache between changes to see the problem more clearly.

I tested a little more and found that I could get rid of the user in the template and print request.user right on the view (which prints to the development server console) and that also fixed the problem of showing a cached page to an authenticated user but that's an ugly hack.

A similar problem was reported here but never got an answer:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/django-users/FyWmz9csy5g/discussion

I can probably write a conditional decorator to check if user.is_authenticated() and based on that use @never_cache on my view but it seems like that defeats the purpose of using per-site cache, doesn't it?

```
"""
A decorator to bypass per-site cache if the user is authenticated. Based on django.views.decorators.cache.never_cache.
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060036/why-django-1-4-per-site-cache-does-not-work-correctly-with-cache-middleware-anon
"""     

from django.utils.decorators import available_attrs
from django.utils.cache import add_never_cache_headers
from functools import wraps

def conditional_cache(view_func):
    """
    Checks the user and if it's authenticated pass it through never_cache.
    This version uses functools.wraps for the wrapper function.
    """ 
    @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
    def _wrapped_view_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            add_never_cache_headers(response)
        return response
    return _wrapped_view_func
```

Any suggestions to avoid the need of an extra decorator will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just confirmed my "problem" was caused by Django lazy loading the User object.

To confirm it, I just added something like this to my view:

test_var = "some text" + request.user

And I got an error message telling me I couldn't concatenate an str to a SimpleLazyObject. At this point the lazy loading logic hasn't got a real User object yet.

To bypass the lazy loading, hence return a non-cache view for authenticated users, I just needed to access some method or attribute to triggers an actual query on the User object. I ended up with this, which I think it's the simplest way:

bypass_lazyload = request.user.is_authenticated()

My conditional_cache decorator is no longer needed, although it was an interesting exercise.

I may not need to do this when I finish working with my views as I'll access some user methods and attributes on my templates anyway but it's good to know what was going on.

Regards.